# How to give itemId to togglebutton inside Ext.panel.panel?

Tags: extjs, automated-tests, panel, togglebutton

I have an **Ext.panel.panel** which is collapsible. Now, I need to give the collapsible toggle button an itemId so I can simulate clicks for this component in the automated tests. 
I can give an itemId to the panel itself but I can't see any way to give one to its toggle button:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just call `collapse` on the panel? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-collapse

Comment: @Tarabass I just tried that and it is posible, but for some reason the autotest is not expanding/collapsing the panel

Comment: @Tarabass Hey! This turned out to be the answer, I was doing something else wrong. Could you answer the question so I can mark it as right?

Comment: Great! Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @Tarabass dude! can you answer the question so I can mark it as answered and hopefully help other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to simulate clicks. You can call [`collapse`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-collapse) on the panel :)